# We're gonna need a bigger bowl!

Tags: real

It's time for lunch, and I want to eat my favorite Regresso™ Chicken Noodle Soup. Ideally, I would pour all the soup from the can to my bowl, microwave the bowl, then eat the soup. Unfortunately, there's more soup than will fit in the bowl: the bowl will only hold 60% of the soup's total volume. I'm unbelievably lazy, so I refuse to wash more than one bowl.

With this information, I came up with a brilliant idea: pour half of the soup in the bowl, microwave the bowl, eat the soup, and then do the same with the other half of the soup. But there's one problem: Whenever I pour soup, all the liquid comes out before any of the chicken/noodles. And I don't want to eat one bowl of broth and a separate bowl of chicken/noodles without the soup! I want my bowl to contain 50% chicken/noodle and 50% liquid, just how it comes.

**So how can I have my soup and eat it too?**

Summary of requirements:

- I'm very hungry, so I must eat all of the soup.
- Before I even think about putting any soup in my mouth, it better be right out of the microwave in the bowl, 50% chicken/noodle, and 50% liquid.
- I cannot use anything other than the can, bowl, microwave, and my mouth. (No second bowl, no filter, not even a spoon)
- I better not overflow the bowl, or otherwise spill any soup.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you have a definitely-good solution in mind, or are you looking for help with a problem you don't know how to solve? :-)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan This is a real problem I ran into, and I came up with a good solution that satisfies my requirements. Although in practical terms, I'd still probably just use two bowls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know

> how hot you like your chicken noodle soup

but it seems to me that your microwave

> can probably heat a bowl of broth to a temperature much higher than you would actually want to eat

in which case the following might be viable:

> pour liquid into bowl; microwave just the liquid until it is close to boiling (or maybe some lower temperature would do better; figure it out by trial and error); pour liquid back into can; allow to equilibrate; eat out of can.

This doesn't satisfy one of your stated requirements:

> "it better be right out of the microwave in the bowl"

but the reason for that requirement is extremely unclear to me and I am hoping to provoke you into explaining why it is there :-).

---

Here is another approach that seems to me inferior in practice to the above, but I think it satisfies your requirements.

If you empty out as much of the can as you can into the bowl, then if I'm understanding right

> you get all the liquid and 1/5 of the solid matter.

You can

> then pour most of the liquid back until you have equal quantities of solid and liquid in your bowl -- this will be 1/5 of the can. Heat that up, eat it, and then repeat. This time you start with 0.4 cans each of solid and liquid, so you get 0.4 liquid + 0.2 solid in the bowl, you pour back 0.2 liquid, and you get to eat 2/5 of the original can contents in bowl #2. Then on the third iteration you just pour everything into the bowl, heat it up, and eat.

Comment: As you were writing that, I was adding some wording to clarify my attitude to your second requirement :-). I mean, it feels like it's there to exclude an otherwise perfectly good solution that happens not to be the one you were thinking of -- but perhaps I misunderstand.

Comment: Firstly, you have no right to question my soup consuming requirements :) Secondly, the reason for the second requirement is to eliminate solutions such as yours; I want every bit of the soup to go through the microwave, and I don't want to eat it out of the can.

Comment: Well, see what you think of my second approach. It seems worse than the first to me, in practical terms, but you may like it better; at any rate, I don't think you yet have any requirements explicitly stated that rule it out.

Comment: Yes, your second approach is the correct one! I know it is impractical, but I'm willing to work very hard to stay lazy. :)

Comment: I'm glad I was successful in reading your mind :-).

Comment: Aww, you beat me to it

Comment: ...but @Riley, why not just shake the soup can and then pour half of it in the bowl?

Comment: @LinuxBlanket I want to pour the soup carefully to avoid spilling, so whether or not I shake the can ahead of time, the liquid comes out before solids.